# Как работать с ChildRelations в дата сете?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть дата сет с кучей ChildRelations связей. Связи называются ТаблицаГлавная_ПотомокГлавной, и так внутрь до 6 вложений.
Как отобразить в DataGridView допустим Таблицу главную со всеми входящими в неё потомками?

Comment: Winforms или WPF? Предположу, что первое. Посмотрите [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) (без `View` на конце!) А так, стандартным подходом является использование [Master/Detail](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews).

Comment: первое, а слефтджойнить всё это дело никак нельзя? Мне просто нужно литое полотно, но чтобы привязка к dataset осталась. Уже руки чешутся переделать всё без этого подхода, но всё-же думаю, я чего-то не знаю и надо узнать.

Comment: приделал для пущего понимания к этому датасету свой многоуровневый грид... Так оказалось, что ещё некоторые ветки пустые.. Т.е. может быть Родитель 1 запись, потомок 0 записей, потомок потомка 4 записи... С мастер дейтайлом будет совсем грустно выглядеть.